# How can I force a link to a PDF to tell the browser to download it as a PDF?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, nginx, anchor

My application generates a dynamic link to any PDF files that are associated with a product. The link is presented like this:

```
<a href="http://mysite.net/mylink.pdf?uid=db5f3dc108594b34a86ad52c8686ade5%2FMyCompany&amp;expires=1324049275&amp;signature=jrSF87xtHkQDCTvOek6uuMacPRc%3D" target="_blank">Brochure</a>
```

If the user right-clicks and selects "Download Linked File As" (or its equivalent), the file is presented with a ".pdf.png" extension in Google Chrome and Safari. Firefox works appropriately, not sure about Internet Explorer.

I want Firefox and Chrome to know that it is a PDF. Because obviously users are going to try to download these, they are going to save it with the wrong extension, and they won't be able to open the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using "send_data" from within a rails controller to serve the file might I suggest:

```
send_data(
    data, 
    :filename => "filename.pdf",
    :disposition => "attachment",
    :type => 'application/pdf'
  )
```

Where "data" is the contents of the PDF.

For more information checkout the following link:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data

Comment: The file is just being presented with a link_to, but I suppose I could wire that up to an action

Comment: Might want to take a look at: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersModule in that case.  Could add in the disposition in the config

Answer (score 0):

send proper headers in some scripting lang like php or user .htaccess

```
<Files *.pdf>
  ForceType application/pdf
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</Files>
```

Comment: I should have mentioned my web server is nginx

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of the content-disposition header? It allows you to tell the browser to ask the user what to do with the file, rather than try and handle it by itself. I don't think it is part of the HTTP spec, but it is documented by the IETF under [RFC 2183](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt).

You should be able to use whatever language you are using to alter the HTTP headers before they go to the client.  The header you add will look something like this:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.pdf
```

You might also need a Content-Type header:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

Comment: It's a Ruby on Rails applications served from nginx. I am aware of the Content-* headers, I just don't know how to check for the file extension or send the the header to the client.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have any knowledge of Ruby but the HTTPHeader module (http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPHeader.html) looks promising.  Have retagged your question with Ruby.